# When all true, then true in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, boolean

I have 2 arrays:

```
arr1 = np.linspace(1, 10, 10)
arr2 = np.linspace(50, 100, 10)
```

Then I want to do:

```
arr1 * arr2 == arr2 * arr1
```

But I want to get a single `True` as output and not an array of `True`s.

How can I do it?

Comment: Try using `np.all`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if two arrays are equal in all elements using [`np.array_equal`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array_equal.html):

```
np.array_equal(arr1 * arr2, arr2 * arr1)
```

In this particular case, you can reduce an array of bools to a single value using [`np.all`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.all.html):

```
(arr1 * arr2 == arr2 * arr1).all()
```

OR

```
np.all(arr1 * arr2 == arr2 * arr1)
```